# handle ngui's button event programmatically in unity

Tags: c#, button, delegates, ngui

I'm transferring from Unity's UI to NGUI.

Formerly, I could add listeners to button with following scripts:

```
button.GetComponentInChildren<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() =>
{
    //codes that could be triggered by click the button. 
});
```

But when changing to NGUI, I can't make it work by:

```
EventDelegate.Set(go.GetComponent<UIButton>().onClick, OnButtonClickActive);

private void OnButtonClickActive()
{
   Debug.Log("active button clicked");
}
```

Comment: what is the compile-time error?

Comment: @kennyzx no error showed. just not work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I made this work by adding a custom event to `OnClick` with the following script (using `UIEventListener`):

```
UIEventListener.Get(go).onClick += OnButtonClickActive;
```

And the event handler is defined as follows:

```
private void OnButtonClickActive(GameObject go)
    {
        int level;
        int.TryParse(go.GetComponentInChildren<UILabel>().text, out level);
        Debug.Log(level + "active button clicked");
        ApplicationModel.CurrentLevel = ApplicationModel.Levels[level - 1];
        SceneManager.LoadScene("PlayScene");
    }
```

Note that, it might be a little bit silly to pass the parameter (level info) with the `UILable` component in the gameobject. If there is other more elegant way, please let me know.